# Ordenar dados com google chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, google, google-charts

Estou com o seguinte gráfico do google chart: https://jsfiddle.net/ektcghyk/

eu queria Ordenar as colunas da esquerda da seguinte forma: Básico, Abaixo do Básico, Proficiente e Avançado. Atualmente está fora da ordem, há possibilidades dessa alteração ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é só você inverter as posições das labels ?

```
['1º ano', 'Básico', 'Abaixo do Básico', 'Proficiente', 'Avançado'],
['2º ano', 'Básico', 'Abaixo do Básico', 'Proficiente', 'Avançado']
```

Comment: Diego esses dados não são fixos.. eles vem aleatórios do banco de dados. :(

Comment: Então você pode criar um campo na tabela chamado **ordem** talvez. E no seu SELECT fazer um **order by** por esse campo. E o valor deles seriam respectivamente, 1 - Básico, 2 - Abaixo do Básico, 3 -  Pro, 4 - Avançado.

Comment: Entendi brother.. vou fazer isso !! Valeu cara :)